# Python Django - getting error while creating model - extending user model with AbstractUser

Tags: python, django

I am trying to extend the user model using AbstractUser component. But I haven't been successful on this. After reseraching lot I wrote my model Employee(Extended user model) but now I get the below error when I do syncdb.

If anyone can help me by suggesting or running my models.py that would be great. when I run syncdb it asks superuser creation after i give the credentials I get a below error.

```
   Error : (Complete traceback is pasted after the models.py)

return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: epi_employee.emp_id may not be NULL



My models.py

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.conf import settings

# Create your models here.

class Employee(AbstractUser):
    emp_id = models.IntegerField('Employee Id', max_length=5,unique=True)
    dob = models.DateField('Date of Birth', null=True,blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.get_full_name


class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Department Name',max_length=30, unique=True,default=0)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Report(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    dept = models.ForeignKey(Department, verbose_name="Department")
    report1 = models.ForeignKey(Employee,null=True,blank=True, verbose_name=u'Primary Supervisor',related_name='Primary')
    report2 = models.ForeignKey(Employee,null=True,blank=True, verbose_name=u'Secondary Supervisor',related_name='Secondary')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user

def upload_to(instance, filename):
    return 'images/%s/%s' % (instance.user.username, filename)

class thumbnail((models.Model)):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    image = models.ImageField('Profile Pic',null=True, blank=True, upload_to=upload_to)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user


class Passport(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    passport = models.CharField('Passport Number',max_length=15)
    passportissue = models.CharField('Issuing City',max_length=15, default='Bangalore')
    passportcountry = models.CharField('Issuing City',max_length=15, default='India')
    passportstart = models.DateField('Valid From', null=True,blank=True)
    passportend = models.DateField('Valid Till', null=True,blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user


class CurrentAddress(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    address = models.TextField('Current Address')
    city = models.CharField('City', max_length=20, default = 'Bangalore')
    state = models.CharField('State', max_length=20, default= 'Karnataka')
    country = models.CharField('Country', max_length=20, default = 'India')
    mobile1 = models.IntegerField('Mobile1',max_length=12)
    mobile2 = models.IntegerField('Mobile2', null=True, blank=True,  max_length=12)
    landline = models.IntegerField('Land Line',null=True, blank=True,  max_length=12)
    email = models.EmailField('Personal Email Id', blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user
```

COMPLETE TRACE BACK: Please find the complete error which I am getting. Let me know if more information required

```
(testenv1) F:\djangoenv\testenv1\employee>python manage.py syncdb
Creating tables ...
Creating table django_admin_log
Creating table auth_permission
Creating table auth_group_permissions
Creating table auth_group
Creating table django_content_type
Creating table django_session
Creating table epi_employee_groups
Creating table epi_employee_user_permissions
Creating table epi_employee
Creating table epi_department
Creating table epi_report
Creating table epi_thumbnail
Creating table epi_passport
Creating table epi_currentaddress

You just installed Django's auth system, which means you don't have any superuse
rs defined.
Would you like to create one now? (yes/no): yes
Username: admin
Email address: admin@admin.com
Password:
Password (again):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "F:\djangoenv\testenv1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.
py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "F:\djangoenv\testenv1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.
py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "F:\djangoenv\testenv1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
 line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "F:\djangoenv\testenv1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
 line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "F:\djangoenv\testenv1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
 line 415, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "F:\djangoenv\testenv1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\
syncdb.py", line 112, in handle_noargs
    emit_post_sync_signal(created_models, verbosity, interactive, db)
  File "F:\djangoenv\testenv1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\sql.py",
line 216, in emit_post_sync_signal
    interactive=interactive, db=db)
  File "F:\djangoenv\testenv1\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py",
line 185, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
  File "F:\djangoenv\testenv1\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\_
_init__.py", line 126, in create_superuser
    call_command("createsuperuser", interactive=True, database=db)
  File "F:\djangoenv\testenv1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.
py", line 159, in call_command
    return klass.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "F:\djangoenv\testenv1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
 line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "F:\djangoenv\testenv1\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\c
ommands\createsuperuser.py", line 141, in handle
    self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).create_superuser(**user
_data)
  File "F:\djangoenv\testenv1\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py",
line 195, in create_superuser
    **extra_fields)
  File "F:\djangoenv\testenv1\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py",
line 186, in _create_user
    user.save(using=self._db)
  File "F:\djangoenv\testenv1\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line
545, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "F:\djangoenv\testenv1\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line
573, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, upda
te_fields)
  File "F:\djangoenv\testenv1\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line
654, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "F:\djangoenv\testenv1\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line
687, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "F:\djangoenv\testenv1\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", li
ne 232, in _insert
    return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
  File "F:\djangoenv\testenv1\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line
 1511, in insert_query
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "F:\djangoenv\testenv1\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py
", line 898, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "F:\djangoenv\testenv1\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\util.py", lin
e 69, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "F:\djangoenv\testenv1\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\util.py", lin
e 53, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "F:\djangoenv\testenv1\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 99, in
 __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "F:\djangoenv\testenv1\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\util.py", lin
e 53, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "F:\djangoenv\testenv1\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.
py", line 450, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: epi_employee.emp_id may not be NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined `emp_id` as `unique` but not `nullable`, you can add `null=True` to the model,but seems to be that you wanna use `emp_id` as a `primari_key`, so to ensure that the field can not be null and must be unique you maybe wanna use a `models.AutoField`:

```
emp_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

this guarantee that the field is unique an can not be null.

Now, for the `max_length` property and the model's name (`Employee`) I think that `emp_id` will be a number that the company gives you, for example my id in the company where I work is `0001544`, so to avoid that problem you can create a custom manager:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager


class EmployeManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username,  email,emp_id,  password=None):
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('Employers must have an username.')
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Employers must have an email address.')
        if not emp_id:
            raise ValueError('Employers must have an employer id')
        user = self.model(username=username, email=self.normalize_email(email), emp_id=emp_id)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username,  email, emp_id, password):
        user = self.create_user(username,  email, emp_id, password)
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

and then in the models file add this:

```
from myapp.managers import EmployeManager
```

and into your `Employers Model` ass this

```
objects = EmployeManager()
```

then you run `python manage.py syncdb`

hope this helps you, any doubt, tell me.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. Sorry for my ignorance,I am new to Django apologies for that :(  I did try null=True it didn't work earlier
1.  If you see my models.py I have put user as a foreign key in all my models 
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
Now If I follow your approach do I need to change the ForeignKey constarint?  

2. My Employee Model will just have  objects = EmployeManager()  or it will have fields as well(emp_id and dob)? I do not want to give AutoIncrement to emp_id field. 

3. Where do I create this customManager? is it in the same models.py?

Comment: with null=True, must work, 1.- you do not need to change the foreignKey, 2.- your model will have the fields and the objects = EmployeManager(), 3.- create a file named managers.py at the same level than models.py

Comment: Awesome Victor, Thanks for the explanation, I need some time to test this. I guess it should work for me. Once it works Ill accept as answer.

Comment: Accepting this answer as I was able to register user. But I am unable to login to the site, any Idea why?  Do I need to specify any special condition? I will raise a separate question for this. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

You defined `emp_id` `unique` but not nullable.

So when you created the superuser, django raises that `emp_id` can't be null.

If you want it as primary key remove that field.
If you want define it later put in emp_id field `null=True`

Anyway you can read here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields

P.s. I see another error:

```
self.get_full_name()
```

But this is the super behaviour so you could delete it at all.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will try this and let you know If I succeed